# Difference between crash in userspace and kernel space

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Regarding a crash - My Idea is User space program crash will not impact other process whereas Kernel space program crash will reboot the system. Whether my idea is right and why it differs

Comment: What is the question? Some userspace crashes are critical for system too; and some bugs in kernel just prints some info to dmesg and kills current process.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the actual implementation of the OS and on any interaction between processes.

If the OS can't protect itself from buggy or malicious programs or it can't protect programs from one another, a crash of a program may have far reaching consequences.

Also, if you have two interacting programs, an unexpected crash in one may result a crash in the other if there's insufficient error detection and recovery.

Answer (score 0):

I think a Monolithic kernel would do so. But a Micro kernel can reload crashed part then continue to run.

Comment: This has nothing to do with monolithicness(?) per se.